# Gogs build fails with "no buildable Go source files"

Tags: ubuntu, go, gogs

I was trying to install gogs from source following [this guide](https://gogs.io/docs/installation/install_from_source).

However once I navigated to the gogs directory and hit "go build" i got the following error "no buildable Go source files in [PATH-TO-GOGS]"

However all required files seem to be there.

Comment: If you downvote, please let me know in the comments so I can avoid this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go ahead and answer my own question since I figured it out:

cd to gogs directory

```
nano gogs.go
```

Look at the first line for me it was

```
// +build go1.5
```

This means you will at least need go 1.5 to build. Now look at your go version:

```
go --version
```

If this number is smaller, this is the reason your build won't even start.
In my case ubuntu was using an older version located at

```
whereis go
```

I deleted the old binary folder (probably something you shouldn't do) and reinstalled go from scratch, which gave me the corret version and the build worked fine.